# Customizing a specific tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the colour text to grey outside the **ul** class but somehow it's only applying inside the **ul** class. I want it also to apply to **All Microsoft** Link which is inside the **d-flex** class.

I only want the text colour to grey inside of the **nav** bar, not for the whole page.

Here is my code for CSS:

```
nav .navbar-nav li a {
color:grey;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <head>
        <title>
            Testing
        </title>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-5.1.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md d-flex justify-content-start">
                
                <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-start"><img src="img/microsoft.png" alt="microsoft" style="width:70px;" height="40px;"></a>
                <span class="navbar-text">Microsoft</span>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.google.com">Microsoft 365</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.facebook.com">Office</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Windows</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Surface</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Xbox</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Deals</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Support</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">All Microsoft</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item material-icons justify-content-end">
                        search
                    
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item material-icons justify-content-end">
                        shopping_cart
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item material-icons justify-content-end">
                        account_circle

                    </li>
                          
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```css
nav > a,
.navbar-nav a[href='https//www.microsoft.com'] {
color:grey;
}
```

```html
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md d-flex justify-content-start">
                
                <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-start">
                  <img src="img/microsoft.png" alt="microsoft" style="width:70px;" height="40px;">
                </a>
                <span class="navbar-text">Microsoft</span>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.google.com">Microsoft 365</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.facebook.com">Office</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Windows</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Surface</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Xbox</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Deals</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="https//www.microsoft.com">Support</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">All Microsoft</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item material-icons justify-content-end">
                        search
                    
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item material-icons justify-content-end">
                        shopping_cart
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item material-icons justify-content-end">
                        account_circle

                    </li>
                          
                </div>
            </nav>
```